# autocapitalizationType Not working

Tags: ios4, uitextfield

I am trying to keep the first charactor of textFiled "Capital" by setting autocapitalizationType but it is not working. below is snapshot of src code for same.

```
UITextField* returnTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
returnTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
returnTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
returnTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
returnTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
returnTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;  
returnTextField.delegate = self;
```

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 20):

If you type in the text field using your hardware keyboard, it ignores auto capitalization. However if you use the keypad on the simulator screen, it should auto-capitalize the words.

Comment: Thanks, I was running into that same behavior, compounded by the different behavior in the Simulator vs the device.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, problem goes from Device settings, if you turn off Autocapitalization on device Settings->General->Keyboard then it will affect on all your applications.

Answer (score 12):

I also find that you should be using the `Default` keyboard as opposed to restricted keyboards e.g. `Name Phone Pad`

Comment: This is a very important step to do. To me this helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you turn off autocorrection then auto-capitalization doesn't work either.  Seems to me that they should operate independently.  In a name field one would want to capitalize every word but not replace a name automatically with whatever the dictionary predicts.

Answer (score 0):

Comment the following line and try.

```
returnTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```